# Android Build error with invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8)

Tags: codenameone

My codename one project has been built and run on the simulator successfully.
I send to android build to your server but failed and generated error.txt.
The main error message in the following:

> Task :mergeDebugResources FAILED
> :mergeDebugResources (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 2.915 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

> /tmp/build295040897406194978xxx/VisionClass/src/main/res/values/strings.xml:3:29: Error: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x8) was found in the element content of the document.

Comment: Did you check that position in that particular file? What is the econding of the file? Maybe you pasted UTF-16 into a UTF-8 encoded document? Try deleting a few characters around that position and *retyping*  (ie not copy&paste) them

Comment: My source files don't include the strings.xml file. I think the file is generated by the build server.

Comment: The manifest XML file is listed fully in the error txt file and you can look in it to see which attribute includes that invalid character. Then fix the string in codenameone_settings.properties.

Comment: I created a new codenameone project and copy the original src folder into the new project. Build successfully.

Comment: So I'm guessing there's a problem in codenameone_settings.properties.